# Control Gameobject on Swipe Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, controls, swipe

Im new on unity and developing a game like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appadvisory.booooing&hl=en . I want to control my gameobject on swipe like the ball in game. How should i code to do so?,Im biggner in unity developing to make game like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appadvisory.booooing&hl=en. I want to control my game object on swipe like the ball in provided link. What will be the code?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The following script will detect swipe in all  direction.

Put your logic in the following functions

```
OnSwipeLeft() 
OnSwipeRight() 
OnSwipeTop() 
OnSwipeBottom()
```

This script will only detect swiping on screen,

Based on the swipe direction, add force, velocity or translation to the ball

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SwipeDetector : MonoBehaviour {

    private const int mMessageWidth  = 200;
    private const int mMessageHeight = 64;

    private readonly Vector2 mXAxis = new Vector2(1, 0);
    private readonly Vector2 mYAxis = new Vector2(0, 1);

    private readonly string [] mMessage = {
        "",
        "Swipe Left",
        "Swipe Right",
        "Swipe Top",
        "Swipe Bottom"
    };

    private int mMessageIndex = 0;

    // The angle range for detecting swipe
    private const float mAngleRange = 30;

    // To recognize as swipe user should at lease swipe for this many pixels
    private const float mMinSwipeDist = 50.0f;

    // To recognize as a swipe the velocity of the swipe
    // should be at least mMinVelocity
    // Reduce or increase to control the swipe speed
    private const float mMinVelocity  = 2000.0f;

    private Vector2 mStartPosition;
    private float mSwipeStartTime;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        // Mouse button down, possible chance for a swipe
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            // Record start time and position
            mStartPosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x,
                                         Input.mousePosition.y);
            mSwipeStartTime = Time.time;
        }

        // Mouse button up, possible chance for a swipe
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            float deltaTime = Time.time - mSwipeStartTime;

            Vector2 endPosition  = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x,
                                               Input.mousePosition.y);
            Vector2 swipeVector = endPosition - mStartPosition;

            float velocity = swipeVector.magnitude/deltaTime;

            if (velocity > mMinVelocity &&
                swipeVector.magnitude > mMinSwipeDist) {
                // if the swipe has enough velocity and enough distance

                swipeVector.Normalize();

                float angleOfSwipe = Vector2.Dot(swipeVector, mXAxis);
                angleOfSwipe = Mathf.Acos(angleOfSwipe) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

                // Detect left and right swipe
                if (angleOfSwipe < mAngleRange) {
                    OnSwipeRight();
                } else if ((180.0f - angleOfSwipe) < mAngleRange) {
                    OnSwipeLeft();
                } else {
                    // Detect top and bottom swipe
                    angleOfSwipe = Vector2.Dot(swipeVector, mYAxis);
                    angleOfSwipe = Mathf.Acos(angleOfSwipe) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                    if (angleOfSwipe < mAngleRange) {
                        OnSwipeTop();
                    } else if ((180.0f - angleOfSwipe) < mAngleRange) {
                        OnSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        mMessageIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        // Display the appropriate message
        GUI.Label(new Rect((Screen.width-mMessageWidth)/2,
                           (Screen.height-mMessageHeight)/2,
                            mMessageWidth, mMessageHeight),
                  mMessage[mMessageIndex]);
    }

    private void OnSwipeLeft() {
        mMessageIndex = 1;
    }

    private void OnSwipeRight() {
        mMessageIndex = 2;
    }

    private void OnSwipeTop() {
        mMessageIndex = 3;
    }

    private void OnSwipeBottom() {
        mMessageIndex = 4;
    }
}
```

For more Information, refer this [Detect Swipe](https://answers.unity.com/questions/600148/detect-swipe-in-four-directions-android.html)